# .pri files showed as .pro files in qt creator

Tags: qt, ide, editor, qt-creator, qmake

do you know if there's a way to not show the .pri files in the project left bar of qt creator? context: I want to manage library dependencies using .pri files. The problem is that now each .pro depends on many .pri files and when I open it in qt creator, I see a list of all the .pri files included by .pro. Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a close button on the bar to get it close and you can also set from the view options

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk are you suggesting to use another view or what?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to hide these files. "Projects" view there is kinda supposed to show the project files, after all. But some options for you:

- Try unchecking "simplify tree" for the Projects to have a tree where you can collapse parts of it.
- Try Documents view
- Try File System view

And most imporant:

- Hide the whole panel where Projects is with Alt+0 so it doesn't bother you.
- Use Ctrl+K locator to switch between files. Really, it's the best thing since sliced bread, just like similar features in other IDEs. Default for it is to list your files, so as an example you can just do *Ctrl+K m Enter* and that will probably take you to main.cpp. Or, *Ctrl+K letter Space something* for other kinds of navigation keywords. It shows decent enough help when you just hit *Ctrl+K*.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. Yes, ctrl+K is kind of God Mode. I know the other views and options, but really.. not seeing the .pri in the project view would be much better. Maybe there is a way in some hidden settings